# Using decimal.Decimal type in gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a gorm struct like the following.

```
type Book1 struct {
    ID     uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Title  string
    Price  decimal.Decimal `sql:"type:decimal(20,8);"` //github.com/shopspring/decimal
}
```

Using `db.AutoMigrate(&Book1{})` i am able to create table in `postgres` but getting type of price as numeric type. On `sqllite` it is creating `"price" decimal(20 , 8)`field correctly.

But when I tried to add the following entry

```
b := Book1{
        ID:    10,
        Title: "hello",
        Price: decimal.NewFromFloat(10.2),
}
er := db.Debug().Create(&b).Error
```

on postgres it is producing error `encode: unknown type for decimal.Decimal`
but on sqlite it add empty value for price.

Debug log prints `INSERT  INTO "book1" ("id","title","price") VALUES (10,'hello','10.2')`

Comment: The debug log seems to show that the decimal.Decimal was encoded properly into `'10.2'` but you still got that error back? Also take a look at this issue: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/2661

Comment: thanks. more info related to this issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30870, [Decimal decompose interface](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal/issues/152)